# Why does fbset -i report a different resolution?

Tags: framebuffer

I'm exploring the linux frame buffer, */dev/fb0*, and when I run `sudo fbset -i` from a virtual console in Gnome 3 (using Terminator) on Fedora 23, it reports the dimensions of the frame buffer as 1280x768, but my Gnome desktop resolution is 1680x1050. Why is *fbset* telling me that the frame buffer is 1280x768?

Full output of `fbset -i`:

```
mode "1280x768"
    geometry 1280 768 2048 2048 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : svgadrmfb
    Address     : (nil)
    Size        : 16777216
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 1
    YPanStep    : 1
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 8192
    Accelerator : No
```

Comment: Gnome doesn't use framebuffer API, it use DRM to show your desktop (Basically, all modern GUI program  does this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer** You are running the command in one display, and fbset is telling you about another one.  These two displays are the *framebuffer*, which runs the tty? CLI screens, and the *display manager*, which provides your Gnome session.

**The longer answer** The *framebuffer* is used while you boot, and for the text consoles you typically get to with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.

Gnome is a *display manager* that also provides an X server for graphics applications.  They are mostly independent of one another, but in most systems they do share a common "Direct Rendering Manager" or DRM driver. This allows you to swap between them without having to reset the video hardware or see strange graphics garbage (like we had to do years ago when X-servers ran completely in user space and talked directly to hardware).  It also allows for a nice smooth transition from the framebuffer-based boot screen to the display manager-based greeting screen.

You may find that when you <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to get to the framebuffer tty2 console, then login and try playing with `fbset` it will make a lot more sense.  Although I need to conclude with a bit of warning.  It may still not work like you think it should.  Many modern frame buffers don't actually change the hardware resolution, but only change a "window" against that screen.  So, you can select a lower resolution in fbset, but it will not make the images larger, it will only limit the text output to a smaller block aligned to the top left of your screen.  If someone could answer how to get that to work properly, I'd be very interested.

If you really want to dig deeper, then check out [this site](http://moi.vonos.net/linux/graphics-stack/). There is a nice picture that ties everything together there.

Answer (score -1):

Gnome is using a different framebuffer device, and changing its resolution; whereas fb0 is one used by virtual consoles.